# Would salt cause a pistachio nut not to be able to germinate?

Tags: trees, seeds, germination

If I buy a bag of pistachio nuts that have been hand picked off the tree when ripe, then salted in a (light) saltwater solution, then vacuum-sealed, and stored in a refrigerator, then will they germinate if I take them out and soak them in a moistened towel laying out in the sun?

Comment: Aren't commercial pistachios roasted?

Comment: These aren't commercial. They've been hand picked as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article https://wikifarmer.com/how-to-grow-pistachio-tree-from-nut/

says unsalted.  Lots more on that site about growing them.